# How to check a class and then replace data-id for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my HTML tag like this:

```
<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{dynamic.ID}"></li>
```

Its generated dynamically 1 to 5 times max.

How can I check each li class, and then change its element data-slide-to="" content attribute to a specific value? for example a different number.

for example on DOM ready the content is this:

```
<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>

<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>

<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
```

and rewrite it dynamically like this:

```
<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0"></li>

<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>

<li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```

vanilla Java Script is what I would like to do, but I guess i would be happy with jQuery as well.

Comment: classes shouldn't have identifiers like that. Without it, this would be a simple find by className, iterate and make changes.

Comment: not sure what you are trying but still you can try something like use the same class name for all of them use id attribute to have your dynamic value and then retrieve by class name (you will get object array) and then try iterating in that object array with ids..

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what code you actually have and what result you want, and where in the process you are stuck.

Comment: Ok yes I can use the same class name. however my data-slide-to="{dynamic.ID}" is different for each li tag. that's what I need to rewrite dynamically. Is that any clearer? I just dont know how to achieve this. I dont know how to get each element and rewrite its data-slide-to="" of each li tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this be helpful

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  // for demo purpose, read existing value into the li's inner text
  li[i].textContent = 'old value: ' + li[i].getAttribute('data-slide-to');
  
  // change it
  li[i].setAttribute('data-slide-to', i);

  // for demo purpose, read it back into the li's inner text to show new value
  li[i].textContent += ' - new value: ' + li[i].getAttribute('data-slide-to');

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>

  <li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>

  <li class="myclass" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But this is a workaround. You are setting looping iterations in `data-slide-to`. What in case user wants to set the new values to 10,20 or maybe 1000.

Comment: this is it. works. it rewrites the data-id I needed. which is my case is generated via back-end and cannot be changed. so it does exactly what I need in front end. it rewrites the data-id to start from 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Alright, then I must have misunderstood slightly. No problem. Your query got solved. Cheers!! @user2513846

Comment: Thanks again @aakash

Answer (score 0):

Its slightly hard to understand as to what exactly you want but I have still come up with a fiddle.

I created a `random` number from 1 to 5 and then looped through each `li` by using jquery's `each` function and then checked if that `li.hasClass` of `random`. If this doesn't make sense, look at the code and the fiddle.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var random=Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

    $('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass(random)){
        $(this).attr('data-slide-to',random);
   }
  });

});
```

Check the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wxfr7sa0/1/

Hope this helps!!Let me know in comments if this is not what you want.

Comment: thank-you! sorry for not being clear. I edited my question, let me know if it make sense.

Comment: You asked in your question to check each `li` class. Now it doesn't make sense as all the classes are same. I am doing one more tweak to my fiddle. Will ping once done.

Comment: yes because on the comments in my question people complained it was easier if I had the same class name. so I can do that if it makes this easier. I can work with vice-versa. All I care is that I can rewrite the content of the data- attribute to a different value

Comment: Better if you don't keep the same classes name as you won't be able to give different values to different `data-slide-to` as you want in your post. If you give them `same classes`, then on generation of random number there would be no way to distinguish your `li` elements as they have the same `classes` and they will end up having the same `data-slide-to` value.